# Are there conflict between RouteValueDictionary and htmlAttributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, actionlink, routevalues

I am using a RouteValueDictionary to pass RouteValues to a ActionLink:

If I code:

```
<%:Html.ActionLink(SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_First, Model.ActionToExecute, Model.ControllerToExecute, Model.FirstRouteValues, null)%>
```

The link result is Ok:

```
SearchArticles?refSearch=2&exact=False&manufacturerId=5&modelId=3485&engineId=-1&vehicleTypeId=5313&familyId=100032&page=0
```

But if i code:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_First, Model.ActionToExecute, Model.ControllerToExecute, Model.FirstRouteValues, new { @title = string.Format(SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_LinkTitle, 0) })%>
```

The link result is:

```
SearchArticles?Count=10&Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D
```

What's the problem? The only difference is that in the last i am using htmlAttributes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of the ActionLink helper. There's no overload that takes `routeValues` as a `RouteValueDictionary` and `htmlAttributes` as an anonymous object. So if `Model.FirstRouteValues` is a `RouteValueDictionary` then the last argument must also be a `RouteValueDictionary`  or a simple `IDictionary<string,object>` and not an anonymous object. Just like that:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_First, 
    Model.ActionToExecute, 
    Model.ControllerToExecute, 
    Model.FirstRouteValues, 
    new RouteValueDictionary(
        new { 
            title = string.Format(SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_LinkTitle, 0) 
        }
    )
) %>
```

or

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(
SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_First, 
Model.ActionToExecute, 
Model.ControllerToExecute, 
Model.FirstRouteValues, 
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "title", somevalue  } })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no overload that matches your parameters, you should either use `object` for route **and** html or `RouteValueDictinary` and `IDictionary<string,object>`.

Like so:

```
Html.ActionLink(SharedResources.Shared_Pagination_First, Model.ActionToExecute, Model.ControllerToExecute, Model.FirstRouteValues, new Dictionary<string.object> { { "title", somevalue  } })
```